# 1970s code-cracking game, similar to Mastermind

Tags: identify-this-game

I am trying to identify a 1970s game similar to Mastermind, which involved cracking a code consisting of a few numerals. I believe the name was something like Quikwit, or Kwikwit - I'm uncertain of the spelling. As with Mastermind, I think solving attempts were 'scored' with pegs.

Comment: There is/was a mastermind with numbers: https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/13609/number-mastermind